In Node.js how to dynamically crop/trim mp4 video file from AWS S3 and return it via streaming to HTML Video player
const res = await pipeline(
        initiateObjectStream(videoKey, start, end),
        response,
      );

I have the functionality of a webinar platform. It has a recorded video that needs to be played as if it were a real video for the user. For example, a webinar starts at 02:00 PM. When a person logs in at 02:15 PM, I need to start streaming the video file in the HTML Video player not from the beginning, but from 15 minutes into the video. That is, I need to dynamically trim the beginning of the video according to the time that has passed since the start of the webinar. If I do this on the front-end, the user can understand that it is a recording or somehow rewind the video through code or other tools. For this project, from a business perspective, it is important that a person cannot understand that this is a recorded video being broadcast
export async function* initiateObjectStream(
      Key: string,
      start: number,
      end: number,
    ): AsyncGenerator<any, any, unknown> {
      const streamRange = `bytes=${start}-${end}`;
    
      const getObjectCommand = new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key,
        Range: streamRange,
      });
    
      const { Body: chunks} = await s3Client.send(getObjectCommand);
   
    
      for await (const chunk of chunks) {
        yield chunk;
      }
    }

I'm using this function to get an mp4 video file, which will then be streamed to an HTML video player
I need to dynamically trim the mp4 video file stored on AWS S3 based on the start, end arguments and return it to the person's browser immediately without saving it
At the beginning of each video file there is metadata, without which HTML Video player does not understand how to play the video. When I pull a file from AWS not from the beginning, but from some part of it, I get a video fragment that no longer has the first chunks of data with metadata. Because of this, the HTML video player closes the stream after receiving the first 3 chunks in which it expects metadata

I was trying to add metadata by another chunks, but it didn't help me
export async function* initiateObjectStream(
  Key: string,
  start: number,
  end: number,
): AsyncGenerator<any, any, unknown> {
  const streamRange = `bytes=${start}-${end}`;

  const getObjectCommand = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key,
    Range: streamRange,
  });

  const { Body: chunks } = await s3Client.send(getObjectCommand);

  //@ts-ignore
  const passThroughStream = new PassThrough();

  const ftypChunk = Buffer.alloc(28);
  ftypChunk.writeUInt32BE(28, 0);
  ftypChunk.write('ftyp', 4);
  ftypChunk.write('mmp4', 8);
  ftypChunk.write('isom', 12);
  ftypChunk.write('iso2', 16);
  ftypChunk.write('mp41', 20);
  ftypChunk.write('mp42', 24);

  const mdatChunk1 = Buffer.alloc(8);
  mdatChunk1.writeUInt32BE(8, 0);
  mdatChunk1.write('mdat', 4);

  const mdatChunk2Size = 303739;
  const mdatChunk2 = Buffer.alloc(8 + mdatChunk2Size, 0x01); // I don't know what I need to do on this part
  mdatChunk2.writeUInt32BE(8 + mdatChunk2Size, 0);
  mdatChunk2.write('mdat', 4);

  const moovChunkSize = 6202;
  const moovChunk = Buffer.alloc(8 + moovChunkSize, 0x02); // I don't know what I need to do on this part
  moovChunk.writeUInt32BE(8 + moovChunkSize, 0);
  moovChunk.write('moov', 4);

  passThroughStream.write(ftypChunk);
  passThroughStream.write(mdatChunk1);
  passThroughStream.write(mdatChunk2);
  passThroughStream.write(moovChunk);
  passThroughStream.end();

  for await (const chunk of passThroughStream) {
    yield chunk;
  }

  //@ts-ignore
  for await (const chunk of chunks) {
    yield chunk;
  }
}

I also tried to use this library in such a format to share method chunks with chunks of the video fragment itself, but that didn't help either.
const ffmpegStream = ffmpeg()
    .input(chunks)
    .format('mp4')
    .addOutputOptions(
      '-movflags +frag_keyframe+separate_moof+omit_tfhd_offset+empty_moov',
    )
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('Processing finished !');
    });

  const ffstream = ffmpegStream.pipe().on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('ffmpeg just wrote ' + chunk.length + ' bytes');
  });

How can I dynamically using "start" parameter (which tells from which timecode to start playing the video), stream an mp3 video file to the HTML Video player, preserving its metadata and without saving the cropped file, so that it all happens on the fly?
